# Why isn't "renderAllHiddenFieldsAtTopOfForm" not working?

Tags: asp.net, forms, seo, asp.net-4.0

In a .NET 4 web application I've set the property "renderAllHiddenFieldsAtTopOfForm" to "false" in the web.config. Unfortunately the hidden fields are still at the top.

Why is this? Does some other setting override it?

*"pages" property in web.config:*
[image: "pages" property in web.config]

*Screenshot of top of the form:*
[image: Screenshot of top of the form]ide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.renderallhiddenfieldsattopofform.aspx):

> all system-generated hidden fields are
>   rendered at the top of the page. This
>   makes sure that the information in
>   these fields is sent to the server
>   even if a postback is performed before
>   the page has finished loading. If
>   RenderAllHiddenFieldsAtTopOfForm is
>   set to false, **performing a postback
>   before the page has finished loading
>   can cause an "Invalid postback or
>   callback argument" error.**
>
> Although the property name indicates
>   "all hidden fields," user-created
>   hidden fields are not affected by
>   settings for this property.

I'm not sure what you are attempting to accomplish here, but it doesn't look like you can do what you are wanting to.  And, for that matter, I'm not sure it's a good idea even if you could.

Comment: If they are system generated then you probably don't have a say in where the controls are placed.  I'm sure they default there whether that value is set to true or false.

Comment: according to MSDN (http://goo.gl/jHr8), that's what "renderAllHiddenFieldsAtTopOfForm" is for.  Did you read the question or am I missing something?

Comment: Either you're missing something or I am.  I didn't see anything that suggests you can "force" the fields to the bottom of the page.  Also, it says "in ASP.NET 3.5 SP1, all system-generated hidden fields are rendered at the top of the page."  So all of the hidden fields get generated at the top of the page in 3.5 SP1 + and there is some other information for .net versions less than 3.5 SP1 (I see you are using 4.0 though, so that doesn't apply)

Comment: np, sorry it's not quite the answer you were hoping for.